# Reading return values from PHP with Mootools

Tags: php, ajax, mootools

I have been trying to retrieve data via AJAX. I can't seem to be able to 'read' what was sent to me by PHP. Here's the code

```
  $('create_course').addEvent('submit', function(e){
   e.stop();
   flash.setStyle('display', 'none');
   this.set('send', {
    onComplete: function(resp){
     if ($chk(resp))
     {
      console.log($type(resp));
      if (resp == 'true')
      {
       flash.set('html', resp);
       flash.reveal();
      }
      elseif (resp == 'false')
      {
       $$('div.information').dissolve();
       $$('div.options').reveal();
      }

     }
    }
   }).send();
  });
```

A different action will happen when I receive a true and a different one on false.

*This was the code.*

```
  if (is_ajax())
  {
   if ($this->form_validation->run('course_create') === TRUE)
   {
    $course = array(
     'name'  => $this->input->post('name'),
     'description'  => $this->input->post('desc'),
     'price' => $this->input->post('price')
    );


    if ($this->course->create($course))
    {
     echo 'true';
    }
    else
    {
     echo 'false';
    }
   }
   else
   {
    echo validation_errors('<div class="message error"><p>', '</p></div>');
   }
  }
```

Note: I've modified the php and js to just read if there's a response. So this php and js is what is used to be. My point is how do I 'read' the return value in Mootools/JS.

Comment: can you show us the the php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. I think. I used Element.match()

```
$('create_course').addEvent('submit', function(e){
            e.stop();
            flash.setStyle('display', 'none');
            this.set('send', {
                onComplete: function(resp){

                    var is_validated = resp.match("true");

                    if (is_validated)
                    {
                        flash.set('html', resp);
                        flash.reveal();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $$('div.information').dissolve();
                        $$('div.options').reveal();
                    }
                }
            }).send();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add an

```
alert(res);
```

what does it give you ?

instead of

```
if ($this->course->create($course))
    {
     echo 'true';
    }
    else
    {
     echo 'false';
    }
```

could you do

```
if ($this->course->create($course))
    {
     die 'true';
    }
    else
    {
     die 'false';
    }
```

Comment: I've never checked using alert but console.log gives me a

true

Comment: yes but you are doing `$type(resp)` I would have preferred `console.log(resp);`

Comment: I did that already before I thought of looking at the type. it gave me 'true', without the quotes.

Comment: so `console.log(resp == 'true');` give ?

Comment: yeap. What I don't understand is why doesn't the conditional state work.

Comment: you must have a character outputed by PHP that's why I would have use `die`